# *ngIf - reference a property which needs to be set more than once

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-ng-if, wijmo

On `Angular 6`, I've got a WIJMO grid on my template. This grid pulls from a database table. Each row of the grid should have either a `delete` button or an `un-delete` button, depending on `*ngIf else`:

```
<wj-flex-grid>
        <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'ID'" [binding]="'ID'"></wj-flex-grid-column>
        <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'deleted'" [binding]="'deleted'"></wj-flex-grid-column>

        <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'delete/undelete buttons'" [binding]="'buttons'">

            <button *ngIf="!deleted; else unDeleted">Delete</button>
                <ng-template #unDeleted>
                    <button>Un-Delete</button>
                </ng-template>

        </wj-flex-grid-column>
</wj-flex-grid>
```

My problem lies with setting this `deleted` property in the .ts file. I need to set and read this property multiple times AKA for every row of the table - but `*ngIf` only wants to use it after the last time it is defined. 
So for my typescript, which uses a `for loop` on every data item and sets `deleted` property to true or false based on a database column, if the last row of the grid is marked as deleted in the database, then all the buttons will show `undelete` and vice versa:

```
export class myComponent extends WjFlexGridParent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

/////// deleted property //////
////// *ngIf only likes to read this after the last time it is defined //////
    public deleted: boolean;

       loadData() {        
        this.myDatabaseService.get(this.myApiPath)
            .subscribe
            (
                data => {

                  this.setCollectionView(data);
                  this.m_collectionView.trackChanges = true;

                    /////// delete/undelete logic //////
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        if (data[i].deleted == null) {
                            this.deleted = false;
                        } 
                        else if (data[i].deleted !== null) {
                            this.deleted = true;
                        }
                    }
                errorCode => {
                    // this.statusMessage = "";
                }
            }
            );
    }

}
```

How can I get `*ngIf` to read this property after every time it is updated?

Comment: Are you doing `*ngFor` to create the rows? I'm not sure I understand completely, but you need an array of delete flags, one for each row.

Comment: I'm not using `*ngFor` - WIJMO uses one line of code to generate the rows, which I have excluded above. 

It seems like `*ngIf` is only reading the `deleted` property after the `for loop` has completed. Thus, whatever the last row sets the `deleted` property to, is what `*ngIf` uses for every row.

Comment: Your loop doesn't make much sense. You're looping over an entire array but you're overwriting `this.deleted` on every iteration. What is that value supposed to contain exactly?

Comment: I was hoping `*ngIf` would read the property on every iteration.
`deleted` property is a boolean - true or false. We don't ever truly delete rows from our database - we instead mark a "Deleted" database column with either `null` (not deleted) or the `ID` number (deleted). This way if an admin needs to 'undelete' a row, they can.

Comment: It looks like the data you are getting already has the deleted attribute, just use that , put the part of the code which creates the rows, I'll post answer based on that..

Comment: I don't think it will help you much since it's WIJMO framework magic which does this. I've included it above, but it's: `this.setCollectionView(data);`. This derives from a parent class. `setCollectionView` is defined in the parent class as: `setCollectionView(p_data) 
    {
        this.m_collectionView = new wjcCore.CollectionView(p_data);
    }`

Comment: @Aragorn You may have better luck looking at my HTML. `WIJMO` binds to the database row via the `[binding]` attribute.

Comment: @Aragorn I'd be really interested to see how `*ngIf` might be able to bind to the .deleted property/key of each `data` row. `data[i].deleted` in this case is the value of the "Deleted" column in the database.

Comment: @Jeto I replied to you above btw..your comment makes sense. I just don't know how to modify this so that `*ngIf` can read the property every time it's overwritten. Perhaps I need to move the property, or maybe not use `*ngIf` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - only one small line of code needed to be changed in the HTML, and the `for loop` in the .ts file can be completely removed.

Special thanks to Jeto and Aragorn in the comments section who pointed me in the right direction, and Sharad from GrapeCity (WIJMO) support for the final answer.

For all you `WIJMO` `FlexGrid` people, I just bound `*ngIf` to my `items.deleted` attribute in the html (similar to what Aragorn suggested when he wrote: `'It looks like the data you are getting already has the deleted attribute, just use that.'`).


**HTML:**

```
    <wj-flex-grid-column [header]="'delete/undelete buttons'" [binding]="'buttons'">

        //// set *ngIf="!item.deleted" ////
        <button *ngIf="!item.deleted; else unDeleted">Delete</button>
            <ng-template #unDeleted>
                <button>Un-Delete</button>
            </ng-template>

    </wj-flex-grid-column>
```

**TS:**

```
loadData() {
    var self = this;

    this.myDatabaseService.get(this.myApiPath)
        .subscribe
        (
            data => {
                this.setCollectionView(data);
                this.m_collectionView.trackChanges = true;

                //// for loop was not needed ////
            },
            errorCode => {
                // this.statusMessage = "";
            }
        );
}
```